# Python 3 porting issue, says a byte-like object is required?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to port a python2 code to python 3.

The following code used to work fine in python 2

```
                   zones = [i.encode("ascii", "ignore").strip(" \"\'")
                           for i in resque_zone]
```

But in Python 3 this gives me the famous "a bytes-like object is required , not str"

```
line 194, in <listcomp>
    for i in resque_zone]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Can someone please help me out

Comment: For future reference, you should try debugging by breaking it down into minimal steps: a `for` loop instead of a comprehension, store the result of `i.encode()` in a variable, then use that variable for `.strip()`, etc. Then you can find what call fails, and print the objects involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to `strip` must be a `bytes` object if you're calling it on a `bytes` string.

```
zones = [i.encode("ascii", "ignore").strip(b" \"\'")
#                                          ^
```

Either that or strip it before you `encode`:

```
zones = [i.strip(" \"\'").encode("ascii", "ignore")
```